# How to Slow Down Axios Get Rate in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently facing an issue where I'm making too many requests to a third-party API too quickly, exceeding the API's request limit rate and resulting in a 409 error status code. My goal is to repeatedly make requests to the API every 5 seconds (the API's rate limit is 1 request per second) but right now it seems that my program is repeatedly making nonstop requests without break.

I've tried wrapping the function that makes the `Axios.get` call (`getCoordinates()`) in a `setInterval()` method with a 5s interval length but it seems to have absolutely no effect; I'm still nonstop requesting without break and ending up with 409 every time. Am I placing things in the wrong spot?

Here is a screenshot of the error message:
[image: Error]

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ISS from "./ISS";
import axios from "axios";

function Map() {
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {   
        setInterval(() => {
            getCoordinates();
        }, 4000)
    }, [])

    const getCoordinates =  async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
            setCoordinates(res.data);
            setLoading(false)
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className="relative w-[620px] h-[475px] map flex content-center justify-center">
            {!loading && <ISS coordinates={coordinates} />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Please post code as TEXT and not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an empty array as the second argument to the useEffect

```js
    useEffect(() => { 
      setInterval(() => {
        getCoordinates()
      }, 5000)  
    }, [])
```